# Pytorch `torch.no_grad()` doesn't affect modules

Tags: pytorch

I was under the (evidently wrong) impression from the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html?highlight=no_grad#torch.no_grad) that `torch.no_grad()`, as a context manager, was supposed to make everything `requires_grad=False`. Indeed that's what I intended to use `torch.no_grad()` for, as just a convenient context manager for instantiating a bunch of things that I want to stay constant (through training). but that's only the case for `torch.Tensor`s it seems; it doesn't seem to affect `torch.nn.Module`s, as the following example code shows:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    linear = torch.nn.Linear(2, 3)
for p in linear.parameters():
    print(p.requires_grad)
```

This will output:

```py
True
True
```

That's a bit counterintuitive in my opinion. Is this the intended behaviour? If so, why? And is there a similarly convenient context manager in which I can be assured that anything I instantiate under it will not require gradient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior, but I agree it is somewhat unclear from the documentation. Note that the documentation says :

> In this mode, the result of every computation will have
> requires_grad=False, even when the inputs have requires_grad=True.

This context disables the gradient on the output of any computation done within the context. Technically, declaring/creating a layer is not computation, so the parameter's `requires_grad` is `True`. However, for any calculation you'd do inside this context, you won't be able to compute gradients. The `requires_grad` for the output of calculation would be `False`. This is probably best explained by extending your code snippet as below:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
     linear = torch.nn.Linear(2, 3)
     for p in linear.parameters():
         print(p.requires_grad)
     out  = linear(torch.rand(10,2))
     print(out.requires_grad)
out = linear(torch.rand(10,2)) 
print(out.requires_grad)
```

```py
True
True
False
True
```

Even if the `requires_grad` for layer parameters is `True`, you won't be able to compute the gradient as the output has `requires_grad` `False`.

Comment: Does this mean that `torch.no_grad()` will save some memory or not? Because, if it doesn't disable gradients for the layer parameters, then these gradients must be stored even if we don't backpropagate. At least this is how I understand `requires_grad=True`.